# how to modify matches to a regular expression with sed or another tool?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need to manipulate text that's in a file.
I need to append a right parenthesis – `)` – after every number
that's preceded by a comma – `,` – e.g.,

- `,4`   ➜ `,4)`
- `,15` ➜ `,15)`

I am struggling to find the proper way to do this with `sed`. I tried the following, which works for 1 digit but can't seem to be extended to 2 digits (so it's fine for first line above but not the second):

```
sudo sed 's/,\([0-9]\)/,\1)/g' filename
```

So then I tried the following for 2 digits:

```
sudo sed 's/,\([0-9]([0-9]?\)/,\1)/g' filename
```

This didn't do anything - the file remained unchanged, though I did not receive an error message. What is the proper way to search for one required digit and a second optional digit and then move them both into the replacement text? I still need to accomplish this:

- `,15` ➜ `,15)`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Certainly the answer with `\{,2\}` is more syntaxically correct but you variant is workable too if your escape "question mark" `\?` and remove extra-bracket `(` between `][` : `sed 's/,[0-9][0-9]\?/&)/g' filename`

Comment: `sed 's/,[0-9]\{1,2\}/&)/g'`. @Costas, `\?` is GNU specific. The portable/standard equivalent is `\{0,1\}`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sure, but if we told re BRE: **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions** In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`,  and  `)`  lose  their  special  meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Comment: @Costas, in GNU BRE only. In standard BRE, there's no `\?` nor `\+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, try this:

```
sudo sed 's/,\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)/,\1\)/g' filename
```

Here in addition to your command i have just added `\{1,2\}` which matches the previous regex between one to two times i.e. from a minimum of one time to a maximum of two times.

`\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)` explained:

- `[0-9]` will match a single digit between 0 to 9
- `{1,2}` will match the previous regex from one to a maximum of two times. So, one match is a must and the second is optional (as you want)
- `()` will make a regex group so that we can reference it later.
- Also note that we have used '\' in front of all extended regex syntax so that they they don't get treated literally. We could have used the `-r` switch (extended regex) with gnu `sed`, in that case we could just write:

  ```
  sudo sed -r 's/,([0-9]{1,2})/,\1\)/g' filename
  ```

**EDIT**: If you want to match any number of digits (minimum one) after comma you can do:

```
sudo sed 's/,\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/,\1\)/g' filename
```

or more simply:

```
sudo sed 's/,\([0-9]\+\)/,\1\)/g' filename
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the command you supplied doesn't seem to work:  ~/html$ sudo sed 's/,([0-9]{,2})/,\1/g' calendar3.php
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Beeb: Aren't you using gnu sed?

Comment: @Beeb: Got it..please check my answer now..

Comment: Thank you for modifying your answer. This worked perfectly. Can you explain it a bit more? In particular I am wondering about these parentheses  --->\([0-9]\{,2\}\)<--- and also the backslashes. Are they actually just a unit together \( and \)? If so, what do they do? Thanks again.

Comment: `\{,2\}` matches from 0 to 2 times.  If you want 1 to 2 times, use `\{1,2\}`.

Comment: @Beeb: Please check my edits..

Comment: @mikeserv: Edited and added..